# How do I use RestClient to post as URL params?

Tags: ruby, post, rest-client

I am posting to an API which accepts CURL as follows:

```
curl -v  -X POST "https://url.com" -d 'input=frustrated&user_key=3b9ccb48e734fce6b982a9c1c2cef301'
```

I have tried the following with an error:

```
    data = {'user_key' => "#{ENV['USER_KEY']}", 'input' => "#{text}", 'client_name'=>> "#{client_name}"}
    talkresponse = JSON.parse(RestClient.post url_talk_bot, {:params => data})
```

for some reason, the data is fine for all except for 'input' which always gets an error as an array which triggers an error since a string is expected.  Note below how the input params is an array.

```
{"user_key"=>"3b9ccb48e734fce6b982a9c1c2cef301", "input"=>"[\"frustrated how do I post to params, worked fine before\"]", "client_name"=>"14155086888"}

 /mnt/task/__gems__/gems/rest_client-1.7.3/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:48:in `return!': 401 Unauthorized (RestClient::Unauthorized)
```

Comment: Why not use [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb), which wraps libcurl nicely.

Comment: +1 to `curb`. Even better if you do a lot of HTTP work: [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday).

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar issues when using RestClient.post.
So much so, that I stopped using .post and started using .execute

- RestClient.post uri, {:params => data}

becomes

- RestClient.execute({ :method => :post, :url => uri, :headers => {api_key: '123', authorization: Base64::encode("#{user}:#{password}"}, :payload: body})

Comment: ugh --- does it mean time to look for another http client other than rest client?